# Odd-Even Index String Sort

Tags: c#, linq

Task:

> Implement the method  at each iteration of which, the odd characters of the string are combined and wrapped to its beginning, and the even characters are wrapped to the end.
> "source" The source string.
> "count" The count of iterations.

My code:

```
        public static string ShuffleChars(string s, int count)
        {
        string res = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
            {
            res = $"{string.Concat(s.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0))}{string.Concat(s.Where((x, i) => i % 2 != 0))}";
            }
        }
        return res;
```

I sorted string but I don't know how can I do iterations on same value  , I tried use "for" , but it is not working, help me pls

i need to sort like this:

1."123456789"

2."135792468" first iteration

3."159483726" second iteration

4."198765432" third iteration

but if I use loop , anyway count = 2 or count = 10 it returns "135792468", I don't know why

Comment: Also, `string.Concat` can be used instead of `string.Join` if you're not joining the items in the collection with anything.

Comment: @RufusL okay , I am just editing my question that moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your problem correctly, you pretty much want to do what your code is doing; shuffle the characters at odd positions to the beginning and even positions to the end.

However, you want to continue to shuffle them, the number of times that you pass in, `count`. If you try to just loop what you have, you're continuing to use the original string that you passed in, s, and then will always end up returning the same value.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to declare an output string that you continue to assign to until you break out of the loop. So something like:

```
public static string ShuffleChars(string s, int count)
{
    var output = s;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       output = string.Join("", output.Where((v, j) => j % 2 == 0)) 
       + string.Join("", output.Where((v, j) => j % 2 != 0));
    }
    return output;
}
```

The key here is that you are declaring a new value, `output`, and initializing it to your string value you passed in. Then for each iteration of the loop, you reassign the value of `output` to the new value. Finally, once you break out of the loop, you return the final value of `output`.

As others have stated, there are other ways you could improve on the assignment line. Personally, I probably prefer using string interpolation:

```
output = $"{output.Where((v, j) => j % 2 == 0)}{output.Where((v, j) => j % 2 != 0)};"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems with your code are:

1. You `return` from inside the loop. This prevents any but the first iteration to complete.
2. You use `<=` instead of `<` in your loop condition. Since we start at `0`, this will iterate `count + 1` times.
3. You use the same variable name `i` for the loop counter as you do in the `Where` clause, which is illegal since they're in the same scope.

To resolve these issues (and use `string.Concat` instead of `string.Join`):

```
public static string ShuffleChars(string s, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        s = string.Concat(s.Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 0)) +
            string.Concat(s.Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0));
    }

    return s;
}
```

Testing the output:

```
static void Main()
{
    var input = "123456789";

    Console.WriteLine($"Starting input   = {input}");
    Console.WriteLine($"One iteration    = {ShuffleChars(input, 1)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Two iterations   = {ShuffleChars(input, 2)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Three iterations = {ShuffleChars(input, 3)}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I have the same task, however what if the `value` is `int.MaxValue` how can we optimize this code for speed and performance? I also asked a question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226053/how-to-shuffle-string-characters-to-right-and-left-until-int-maxvalue)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `string` to an `IEnumerable<char>`, and then apply the same [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) transformations a `count` number of times. Finally materialize the `IEnumerable<char>` to a `char[]` using the [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) operator, and then convert the array back to a `string`.

```
public static string ShuffleChars(string s, int count)
{
    IEnumerable<char> chars = s;
    foreach (var _ in Enumerable.Range(0, count))
    {
        chars = chars
            .Select((c, i) => (c, i))
            .OrderBy(e => e.i % 2)
            .Select(e => e.c);
    }
    return new String(chars.ToArray());
}
```